# CSS End a keyframe looping animation and have it animate back to start

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a looping animation that rotates a square. When I remove the class that enables the animation, the square instantly goes back to the starting position.

I need to be able to animate the square back to the starting position on a JS event.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jordanneenan/pen/NExMPq).

I have tried adding a transform to the element, and switching to another keyframe animation but neither worked.

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="animate rotating"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}

.animate{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  transform: all 2s ease;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  0%{transform: rotate(30deg);}
  50%{transform: rotate(-30deg);}
  100%{transform: rotate(30deg);}
}

.rotating {
  animation: rotating 6s ease-in-out infinite forwards;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.animate').click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('rotating');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a little problem with your code:

```
transform: all 2s ease;
```

You mistyped transition, however I'm pretty sure this approach isn't going to work. If you're willing to accomplish this using jQuery you can get current rotation and apply to your element:

```
function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
    var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
    obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
    obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
    obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
    obj.css("transform");
    if(matrix !== 'none') {
        var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var a = values[0];
        var b = values[1];
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
    } else { var angle = 0; }
    return (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
}

$('.animate').click(function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var elRotate = getRotationDegrees(el);
  el.css('transform',`rotate(${elRotate}deg)`);
  el.removeClass('rotating');
  // set new transform here
});
```

This will freeze your element rotation, you can set your desired rotation at the end and transition will be applied.

Comment: Took me a sec to get my head around it, but it works really nicely, thanks!